# Can I reflect HTML libraries in the stand-alone Dart VM?

Tags: dart, dart-html, dart-mirrors

I'm trying to do code generation in the following way: a view is defined in an XML markup, the tags refer to components that are part of a library which imports `dart:html`.

Ideally, I would like to run a vm script (i.e. via a transformer) which parses the markup down to code instructions.

Reflection is being used to partially validate the xml and to detect any necessary binding, for example `<DataGrid id='grid' dataProvider='data' />`

Reflection would check that a dataProvider setter exists and that data is in fact of the correct Type. If data is observable, it would also generate code that grid.dataProvider is bound to data via listeners.

This all works great, but unfortunately only when I run the script in a browser, which is not the idea.

Bottom line, is it at all possible to achieve via the standalone VM? Something like `mirrors.reflectLibrary(String uri)`, without having to specify the import line?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you need reflect for but I guess what you are looking for is https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/html5lib, https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/html5plus, or one of the xml packages available at pub.dartlang.org.
You can't import `dart:html` on command line applications and you can't reflect on code which is not imported.
I have seen source mirrors mentioned a few times but never found out what it is, but it sounds like what you are looking for, maybe someone else knows more.
Another option to work with source code is the analyzer. It creates an AST from source and allows you to inspect the result.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that html5lib is designed to an api compatible with dart:html. But it is not feature complete, for example css selectors are pretty basic.